# How can I change a config file variable using ant build?

Tags: windows, ant, jboss, properties, build

I'm using Jboss 4/5 and have some .war .properties files with default configuration settings

I want to update these settings using information from the windows xp environment variables.

${env} in ant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import enviroment variables before including your property file:

**build.xml** file:

```
<target name="build">
   <!-- load enviroment properties -->
   <property environment="env" />
   <property file="test.properties" />
   <echo>test: ${test}</echo>
</target>
```

**test.properties** file:

```
test = ${env.TEMP}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to up the build number in several files. Since I needed to keep the formatting of the file as well as the comments, I used [replaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html). Be careful when writing your regular expressions that you limit the expression to only find the instances that you care about.

```
<replaceregexp 
    file="${dir.project}/build.properties"
    match="(build\.number[ \t]*=).*"
    replace="\1${build.number}"
    flags="g"
/>
```

Comment: I need to know regular expression to turn on off a variable in project.propreties file.  proguard.config=proguard.cfg turns proguard on and removal turns it off.  What regular expression do I need for this.

Comment: see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629726/how-to-use-custom-ant-rule-regexpression-to-change-property-in-propertyfile