# How to use custom ant rule regexpression to change property in propertyfile

Tags: android, ant

In my Android project I have the following property set in my project.properties file

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

and I need a custom macro that will somehow set and unset this property.

How do I set unset this property using macro and regular expression?
two things I am not clear on is how to set this to an empty property value.  Would
that be just proguard.config=
or proguard.config=''

What would be the Macro for doing this?

```
 <macrodef name="turn-on-proguard">
    <sequential>    
       <replaceregexp file="./project.properties"
                            match='proguard.config="(.*)"'
                            replace='proguard.config=proguard.cfg'
                            byline="false">         
        </replaceregexp>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>



 <macrodef name="turn-off-proguard">
    <sequential>    
       <replaceregexp file="./project.properties"
                            match='proguard.config="(.*)"'
                            replace='proguard.config='
                            byline="false">         
        </replaceregexp>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Would this work?  Update.  turn-proguard-off does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very unclear for me. Why don't you escape the dot character? Why do you use quotation marks and grouping in your regexp?
This is working script:

```
<macrodef name="turnonproguard">
    <sequential>    
       <replaceregexp file="project.properties"
                match='proguard\.config=.*'
                replace='proguard.config=proguard.cfg'
                byline="false"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="turnoffproguard">
    <sequential>    
       <replaceregexp file="project.properties"
                match='proguard\.config=.*'
                replace='proguard.config='
                byline="false"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="on">
    <turnonproguard/>
</target>

<target name="off">
    <turnoffproguard/>
</target>
```