# How to specify a property in replaceregexp

Tags: java, android, regex, ant

I don't know how to specify the wildcard for my.property=anything * ????

I also need to know how to set do a replace that sets my.property to an empty value?

Here is an example:

```
   <replaceregexp file="./project.properties"
                        match='someproperty.value="(.*)"'
                        replace='somepropert.value=othervalue'
                        byline="false">         
    </replaceregexp>
```

Its really very simple what I am asking.  How do I set and unset a property in property file using replaceregexp from an ant script. Thats it.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific. Your question doesn't actually make any sense. (sorry)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use custom ant rule regexpression to change property in propertyfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629726/how-to-use-custom-ant-rule-regexpression-to-change-property-in-propertyfile)

Comment: Am I the only one doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use entity for the "

```
&#34;
```

And escape the dot

```
\.
```

match would look

```
match='someproperty\.value=&#34;.*&#34;'
```

The brackets are unnecessary.